# Trouble installing jquery plugin in rails.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I looked through some related questions suggesting how to maneuver the asset pipeline, but still am unable to get it to work.

index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "playlist" %>

<div class="demo">
  <div class="demoPlate plate" style="margin: 0 auto;">

  </div>
</div>
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require plate.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require bindWithDelay
//= require jquery.datetimepicker
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#event_when").datetimepicker({
    format:'Y/m/d H:i'
  });
  $("#user_dob").datetimepicker({
    timepicker:false,
    format:'Y/m/d',
    maxDate:'0'
  });
});
```

playlist.js:

```
 $(function(){
      $('.demoPlate').plate({
        playlist: [
          {"file":"files/morgantj_-_caf_connection_1.mp3"}
        ]
      });
    });
```

The files that the plugin need to be compiled are:
jquery-ui, jquery, plate.js, and they have playlist.js in the body.

I have tried all ends of the asset pipeline, but cant figure out what im missing.

The instructions they gave for installing are (Screenshots):
[Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9f2C.png)
[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS7S8.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following inside **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require plate.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require bindWithDelay
//= require jquery.datetimepicker
```

You should have all  of these files inside the directory of **app/assest/javascripts**

I will automatically loaded inside one file "application.js" , no need to declare or include inside `<head></head>` tag, **unless** you don't include the **application.js file** in layout.

you can also **require** **playlist.js** after setting up jquery plugins/dependencies